# How to test onClose event in react using jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I'm doing a unit test of a materialui suspended component, but I'm not able to test the handleClose function...

I thought of putting a condition in onClick: onClick={open ? handleClose : handleClick} and then I'll  be able to test that function, but at the same time, I believe it would not be correct aproach...

how could i perform the test?

this is the funcions and states:

```
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {

    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };
```

This is my component:

```
   <Button
        data-testid="button"
        aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : 'false'}
        onClick={handleClick}
        variant="contained"
        color="inherit"
      >
        {label}
      </Button>
      {open && (
      <Menu
        id="basic-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          horizontal: 'left',
          vertical: 'bottom'
        }}
        MenuListProps={{
          'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button'
        }}
      >
        {items.map((item, key) => {
          return (
            <MenuItem
              key={key}
            >
              <Link href={item.route}>
                <a className="flex items-center gap-2 text-sm">
                  {item.label}
                </a>
              </Link>
            </MenuItem>
          );
        })}
      </Menu>
```